# Using iptables to redirect all traffic to my localhost

Tags: networking, iptables, dd-wrt

So I've just installed DD-WRT on my router and I wanted to redirect all http requests to my local host located at `192.168.1.50` (port `80`) but I'm unable to find any way of doing this.

I've tried doing something like `address=/google.com/192.168.1.50` it works but making a giant list would be pain. Is there an easier way to do this? I've looked into using iptables on the router itself but since it was my first time using them I haven't got the results I wanted.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.50
```

Comment: We need some more information. It is likely you need to specify an interface on that line you listed. We also need to know your default policies. It is also likely some POSTROUTING SNAT or MASQUERADE line is needed. I am not familiar with dd-wrt, but wonder if running both would not be compatible. See a similar situation [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2272938), which I'll make an answer here once I have enough information.

Comment: why don't you just use the port forwarding option in DDWRT?

Comment: By the way, I agree with mchid, you should be able to do what you want with DDWRT directly. I can help with the iptables stuff, but not DDWRT

Comment: mchid how would I go about doing that I set the port to and from to 80 and the ip address to 192.168.1.50 but its not going to my localhost.